# Recommended filesystem, mysqltmp and filesystem related settings for a mysqld box running ssd + BIG ram + linux?

Tags: linux, mysql, ssd, filesystems

What is the recommended filesystem + mysqltmp location when dealing with a ssd based system that has some ram to spare?

Currently we run our mysqltmp folder on a 4gb tmpfs partition. Works great. But the box is getting an upgrade that will include a full ssd setup.

1) When dealing with a system that has BOTH ssd and a large amount of ram, where should we place our mysqltmp folder? There ARE some *infrequent* large sorts that end up hitting the mysqltmp.

2) How do we deal with the system swap file when running linux on a ssd setup?

3) What is the recommended file system for a mysqld box running on linux on ssds?

Comment: The best FS is whatever's best supported by your OS.  I suspect that's Ext4

Answer (score 0):

A tmpfs partition will still perform better than a SSD if you need every last oomph of speed. As for filesystem, something newer and production-quality would be best; and these days that's pretty much EXT4 (assuming Linux) or ZFS (if BSD). Btrfs is still technically experimental, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Note that InnoDB can also run directly on block devices, no need for filesystem.  It takes a little planning, but you get the best filesystem: none at all.